# About install jenkins on my local ubuntu 17.10 machine

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins

I'm trying to install jenkins locally
I try these steps:-

1) wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo 
      apt-key add -
2) echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee 
        /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
3) sudo apt-get update

then i get this error:-
       E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-
                 5.4.1.list (Suite)
       E: The list of sources could not be read.

I try to change the mode of this file but i can't do.this is only readable file.

In elastic-5.4.1.list I find this thing:-
  deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-
              5.4.1.deb

Comment: If you just want to run Jenkins then download the WAR and run it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your elasticsearch apt source file (`elastic-5.4.1.list`) is not correct. It must have this format:

```
deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main
```

Once you fix that line, make sure you update your apt repository:

```
apt-get update
```

Refer to documentation for details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html